# Spring Security + CAS Redirect to public page - Authentication object not available

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security, cas

I have a public page with security configuration as

```
<intercept-url pattern="/public/a.jsf" access="permitAll"/>
```

However, that page also has some secure content that is shown only to authenticated users. To see the secure content, users have to click on a login link on that page which redirects them to the CAS login page and brings them back to the same page after successful authentication. Here is the login link

```
<a href="cas_server/login?service=app_server/public/a.jsf">Login</a>
```

Everything works including successful authentication and redirect back to the public page. However, when the user is returned back to the public page, the Spring SecurityContextHolder is not populated and rather still shows the user as Anonymous user. On the other hand, if the service url above is a non-public page such as **/private/b.jsf** and then user navigates back from **b.jsf to a.jsf** the securitycontextholder has the authentication object and the user can see the secure content on **b.jsf**

Is there any way to achieve the redirect to public page after login and not having to go through **b.jsf** and still have the securitycontextholder populate?

Note: On page **a.jsf** the secure content is rendered based on a bean method `#{bean.authenticated}` which checks the securitycontextholder and see if there is any authentication object other than Anonymous

Comment: Did you figure out any solution to this? I'm facing exactly similar problem.

Comment: Unfortunately No. I am still using the redirect option instead of going directly to the page. Its not elegant but getting the job done!

Comment: I'm also using `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to get around this problem.